# Parsing XML reading code to extract legal XML tags

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a codebase that reads in XML files. There seems to be no documentation
for the tags that are read in. There are a couple types of entities, among
those are *monomials* and *solvers*. Internally, there is a factory with a
`map<string, monomial>`. Each monomial has a parameter struct and a `read` and
`write` function.

the XML token I know is `REMEZ`. There is a `const std::string name` that
defines the name that goes into the factory can be found with `grep`:

```
$ git grep REMEZ
lib/update/molecdyn/monomial/remez_rat_approx.cc:    const std::string name = "REMEZ";
```

In that file, `remez_rat_approx.cc`, one can find the constructor and `write`
function of the parameter struct:

```
namespace Chroma {
    void read(XMLReader &xml,
              const std::string &path,
              RemezRatApproxEnv::Params &param) {
        RemezRatApproxEnv::Params tmp(xml, path);
        param = tmp;
    }

    void write(XMLWriter &xml,
               const std::string &path,
               const RemezRatApproxEnv::Params &param) {
        param.writeXML(xml, path);
    }

    namespace RemezRatApproxEnv {
        Params::Params(XMLReader &xml, const std::string &path) {
            XMLReader paramtop(xml, path);

            read(paramtop, "numPower", numPower);
            read(paramtop, "denPower", denPower);
            read(paramtop, "lowerMin", lowerMin);
            read(paramtop, "upperMax", upperMax);
            read(paramtop, "degree", degree);

            if (paramtop.count("digitPrecision") != 0)
                read(paramtop, "digitPrecision", digitPrecision);
            else
                digitPrecision = 50;
        }

        void Params::writeXML(XMLWriter &xml, const std::string &path) const {
            push(xml, path);

            write(xml, "ratApproxType", RemezRatApproxEnv::name);
            write(xml, "numPower", numPower);
            write(xml, "denPower", denPower);
            write(xml, "lowerMin", lowerMin);
            write(xml, "upperMax", upperMax);
            write(xml, "degree", degree);
            write(xml, "digitPrecision", digitPrecision);

            pop(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

In `remez_rat_approx.h` there is the definition of the parameter struct:

```
namespace Chroma {
    namespace RemezRatApproxEnv {
        struct Params {
            Params() {}
            Params(XMLReader &in, const std::string &path);
            void writeXML(XMLWriter &in, const std::string &path) const;

            int numPower;
            int denPower;
            Real lowerMin;
            Real upperMax;
            int degree;
            int digitPrecision;
        };

        class RatApprox : public RationalApprox {
          public:
            RatApprox(const Params &p) : params(p) {}

          private:
            Params params;
        };
    }

    void read(XMLReader &xml,
              const std::string &path,
              RemezRatApproxEnv::Params &param);

    void write(XMLWriter &xml,
               const std::string &path,
               const RemezRatApproxEnv::Params &params);
}
```

An example of valid XML input is the following:

```
<ratApproxType>REMEZ</ratApproxType>
<lowerMin>1.0e-3</lowerMin>
<upperMax>33</upperMax>
<numPower>-1</numPower>
<denPower>4</denPower>
<degree>16</degree>
```

*In principle*, one should be able to extract the allowed tags (and their C++
types) from the C++ source. Just parsing this line-by-line with regular
expressions seems out of the question, though.

There are additional complications because some entities inherit their
parameter `struct`, so one cannot find it in the matching header file. Also
some parameters are optional, like this:

```
if (paramtop.count("Verbose") > 0) {
    read(paramtop, "Verbose", VerboseP);
} else {
    VerboseP = false;
}
```

It seems that I would have to find all invocations of `read` or `write` and
create a structure out of that. Parsing the C++ is probably best left to some
library made for this, perhaps something from LLVM?

Ideally, one supplies such a name and gets the XML tags and their C++ types as
well as a possible default vaule. Is it a feasable undertaking to parse all the
C++ code to get the XML tags read in by some entitiy named by the `const std::string name`? What would be a good starting point?

Comment: *"In prinicple,...", No, tag extraction is only allowed if the definition of the language allows it.  Check out the C++ language standard documentation.

Comment: The XML is a language and may not be suitable for regular expression parsing.

Comment: I recommend using an existing XML library rather than writing your own.

Comment: I also recommend studying Compiler Theory, at a minimum, Lexing and Parsing.

Comment: I do not want to parse the XML. I want to parse the XML *reading code* written in C++ to know what XML it expects.

Comment: Again, studying Compiler theory will help you to parse the C++ code.  There are some free libraries and source code to parse C++ code.  The C++ language is not a simple language and very complicated.  Good parsers take teams of people years to build.